# How to create dependency injection for ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5

Creating Dependency Injection with ASP.NET Core is fairly easy. The documentation explains it very well [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?highlight=dependency#registering-your-own-services) and this guy has a [killer video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5A2UxMGA58g) to explain it.

However, I want to do the same thing with my ASP.NET MVC 5 project. How can handle dependency injection with ASP.MVC 5?

Also, is Dependency injection limited to controllers only or can it work with any class?

Comment: There are many 3rd DI Containers out there, and they all have their own excellent documentation about how to plug-in their container into an MVC app. For instance [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mvcintegration.html), [Autofac](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html) or [Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc).

Comment: For me I would prefer to go with an example project which explains in details and step by step how to use dependency injection for ASP.NET MVC5.. I found it in  a great book called Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 .. chapter 6. interesting book you should read it!

Comment: Chapter 3 for me. Pro ASP.NET MVC 5, 5th edition by Freeman.

Answer (score 55):

In ASP.Net MVC you can use the .Net Core DI from NuGet rather than one of the third-party alternatives:-

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
```

For the MVC Start/Configuration class:-

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // We will use Dependency Injection for all controllers and other classes, so we'll need a service collection
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    // configure all of the services required for DI
    ConfigureServices(services);

    // Configure authentication
    ConfigureAuth(app);

    // Create a new resolver from our own default implementation
    var resolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver(services.BuildServiceProvider());

    // Set the application resolver to our default resolver. This comes from "System.Web.Mvc"
    //Other services may be added elsewhere through time
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);
}
```

My project uses Identity User and I've replaced the OWIN start-up configuration to follow a service-based approach instead. The default Identity User classes use static factory methods to create instances. I've moved that code into the constructors and relied on DI to provide the appropriate injection. It is still work in progress but here is where I am at:-

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{               
    //====================================================
    // Create the DB context for the IDENTITY database
    //====================================================
    // Add a database context - this can be instantiated with no parameters
    services.AddTransient(typeof(ApplicationDbContext));

    //====================================================
    // ApplicationUserManager
    //====================================================
    // instantiation requires the following instance of the Identity database
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IUserStore<ApplicationUser>), p => new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

    // with the above defined, we can add the user manager class as a type
    services.AddTransient(typeof(ApplicationUserManager));

    //====================================================
    // ApplicationSignInManager
    //====================================================
    // instantiation requires two parameters, [ApplicationUserManager] (defined above) and [IAuthenticationManager]
    services.AddTransient(typeof(Microsoft.Owin.Security.IAuthenticationManager), p => new OwinContext().Authentication);
    services.AddTransient(typeof(ApplicationSignInManager));

    //====================================================
    // ApplicationRoleManager
    //====================================================
    // Maps the rolemanager of identity role to the concrete role manager type
    services.AddTransient<RoleManager<IdentityRole>, ApplicationRoleManager>();

    // Maps the role store role to the implemented type
    services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>, RoleStore<IdentityRole>>();
    services.AddTransient(typeof(ApplicationRoleManager));
    
    //====================================================
    // Add all controllers as services
    //====================================================
    services.AddControllersAsServices(typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
        .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
    .Where(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
    || t.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
}
```

The Account Controller class has the single constructor:-

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
        RoleManager = roleManager;
    }
}
```

My Default Dependency Resolver:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides the default dependency resolver for the application - based on IDependencyResolver, which hhas just two methods
/// </summary>
public class DefaultDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the service that holds the services
    /// </summary>
    protected IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    /// <summary>
    /// Create the service resolver using the service provided (Direct Injection pattern)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceProvider"></param>
    public DefaultDependencyResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a service by type - assume you get the first one encountered
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceType"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get all services of a type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceType"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetServices(serviceType);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this but installation failed saying that it did not support the framework I was targetting (4.5.1). I was very sad :(

Comment: @BVernon If you can upgrade to 4.6.1, I think it will let you install it.

Comment: Shouldn't your AccountController private variables be interfaces, not concrete classes?

Comment: @joshmcode Yeah unfortunately that's the problem for me; it's not a good time for us to do that. Eventually we will but I ended up just getting Castle.Windsor as I found some code snippets that handled the two issues I was concerned with: integrating the DI container with the controllers and also with Solr search.

Comment: @pixelda from what namespace do you get "DefaultDependencyResolver"-Class?

Comment: @ joshmcode - quite right, but not a high priority at the moment.

Comment: @Darem, I don't see a built-in DefaultDependencyResolver. Looks like you have to write it yourself? Here's a sample implementation: https://gist.github.com/andriybuday/a96bfc7845ba1514561a4e6f146a629d#file-2-defaultdependencyresolver-cs

Comment: Hello, I am using .NET 4.7.2 with Identity.  Is it true that if I was using .NET core 2+ DI would be built in with the use of the app.CreatePerOwinContext lines within the StartUp's ConfigureAuth function? or does it still require this answer for DI to work correctly? Very confused at this point because the VS template output code has it all set up as if DI works out of the box.  However, I guess that is the reason for the "return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();" in the getter of ApplicationSignInManager. If not set(.Net 4.X) get it

Comment: didn't the OP specifically say ASP.NET MVC 5, and specifically exclude MVC core?  It seems that this code works with .NET core only

Comment: I tried editing the resolver into this answer, since it really should be part of this answer, and it's silly to expect someone reaching this page to review other answers farther down and synthesize them into a working solution. Unfortunately, mods rejected my edit as a drastic change. pixelda, would you mind making that edit yourself?

Comment: im trying to make AddTransient => AddScoped on my ApplicationDbContext but it keeps tuning me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101329/di-scoped-dbcontext-ef6-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a, should your example not be scoped for service and repos

Comment: Hello, in my case compiler shows an error at this instruction: `services.AddTransient<RoleManager<IdentityRole>, ApplicationRoleManager>();`. It says: `Type 'ApplicationRoleManager' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in generic type or method 'ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddTransient<TService, TImplementation>(IServiceCollection)'`. I don't know exact message since I am translating from Spanish. What may be causing this?

Comment: @Seabizkit and anyone else: the linked question is withdrawn so i cannot see what it was, but i guess i wanted to also know if this example should be enough to actually generate Scoped service instances (tied to request lifecycle). when i AddScoped<T> and later retrieve the service, it always comes back the same across multiple requests. possibly need to invoke ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory... per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53993727/asp-net-dependency-injection-scoped-life-time

Answer (score 40):

For this answer I downloaded a [Microsoft Example of WebApi project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) as a basis for the example and added DI services to it as follows,

- Update the Target Framework to 4.6.1
- NuGet the DI package :- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

After the standard MapHttpRoute configuration, add code to register which services you need

*using's*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Web.Http.Dependencies;
using ProductsApp.Controllers;
```

*WebApiConfig*

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // create the DI services and make the default resolver
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddTransient(typeof(DefaultProduct));
        services.AddTransient(typeof(ProductsController));

        var resolver = new MyDependencyResolver(services.BuildServiceProvider());
        config.DependencyResolver = resolver;
    }
}
```

*DefaultProduct*

```
public class DefaultProduct : ProductsApp.Models.Product
{
    public DefaultProduct()
    {
        this.Category = "Computing";
        this.Id = 999;
        this.Name = "Direct Injection";
        this.Price = 99.99M;
    }
}
```

*MyDependencyResolver*

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides the default dependency resolver for the application - based on IDependencyResolver, which hhas just two methods.
/// This is combined dependency resolver for MVC and WebAPI usage.
/// </summary>
public class MyDependencyResolver : System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver, System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver 
{
    protected IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    protected IServiceScope scope = null;

    public MyDependencyResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) 
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public MyDependencyResolver(IServiceScope scope) 
    {
        this.scope = scope;
        this.serviceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope() 
    {
        return new MyDependencyResolver(serviceProvider.CreateScope());
    }

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) 
    {
        scope?.Dispose();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType) 
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType) 
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetServices(serviceType);
    }
}
```

*ServiceProviderExtensions*

```
public static class ServiceProviderExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddControllersAsServices(this IServiceCollection services, IEnumerable<Type> serviceTypes)
    {
        foreach (var type in serviceTypes)
        {
            services.AddTransient(type);
        }

        return services;
    }
}
```

I then amended the existing controller to take the DI type (note there is just the one ctor)

```
using ProductsApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ProductsApp.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        DefaultProduct _dp = null;

        public ProductsController(DefaultProduct dp)
        {
            _dp = dp;
            //
            products.Add(dp);
        }

        List<Product> products = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },
            new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }
        };

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful with `public IDependencyScope BeginScope() { return this; }`. If you do this you will get memory leak. You need to call `_serviceProvider.CreateScope()`, and new constructor to dependency resolver that accepts it and return new resolver instance. Then in `Dispose` dispose the scope.

Comment: Thanks @StanislavBerkov!!  You're right!  I've updated the answer.  How did you know that??

Comment: @spottedmahn I get memory leak in prod and started investigating why)

Comment: @StanislavBerkov after re-reading your comment a few more times I still don’t think we have the correct implementation in this answer.  Thoughts? 

Comment: Thanks @StanislavBerkov!!  Your implementation makes more sense than mine .  Why the virtual dispose though?

Comment: I've follows the instructions here but get the error message: `InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MyApp.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.`.

Comment: `config.DependencyResolver = resolver;` didn't seem to work for me, whereas `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);` did

Answer (score 5):

My Default Dependency Resolver

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides the default dependency resolver for the application - based on IDependencyResolver, which hhas just two methods
/// </summary>
public class DefaultDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the service that holds the services
    /// </summary>
    protected IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    /// <summary>
    /// Create the service resolver using the service provided (Direct Injection pattern)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceProvider"></param>
    public DefaultDependencyResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a service by type - assume you get the first one encountered
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceType"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get all services of a type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceType"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetServices(serviceType);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should edit your initial response to include this.... it's a little out of context as a seperate answer.  Great work though :)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you use [Autofac](https://autofac.org), there are anothers fwk like unity, ninject,  the benchmarks autofac has excelent perfomance.

http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison

Here is the integration with MVC (and works with all class)

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to implements Dependency Injection in ASP.NET MVC 5 is to use the tool developed by Microsoft itself, called `Unity`.

You can find many resources on the internet about it, and you can start by reading the official documentation available here: [Developer's Guide to Dependency Injection Using Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223671(v=pandp.30).aspx)

> Also, is Dependency injection limited to controllers only or can it work with any class?

It works with any class, in any project, as long as you register the Interface related to the Implementation (if you want to take profit of the [IoC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)), all you have to do then is to add the Interface instantiation in your constructor.

Comment: If NuGet complains about Unity having a dependency on a lower version of Newtonsoft.JSON library, try 2-3 times. I tried installing AutoFac which had same issue but successfully resolved by uninstalling old version and using new. Once it was there, I again tried installing Unity with success and then uninstalled AutoFac (just because of more comfort in Unity :) )

Comment: Not down-voting, but Unity seems abandoned (?) : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/08/21/the-future-of-unity/   One comment: "The new owners did almost nothing to keep the project alive. The last commit is almost one year old. The lastest version was released in October 2015. Apparently there has been some work to support .NET Core, but it was never completed. Not a single pull request has ever been merged. And the maintainers don’t even reply to issues and PRs anymore. So, I think it’s official now: Unity is dead…"

Comment: @iokevins Microsoft has a new DI framework for ASP.NET Core.  Turns out it can be included with ASP.NET 4 and used in MVC 5.  It's not as fully featured as other frameworks but it should handle basic use cases for a project.  Otherwise, I agree Unity seems to be dead and other frameworks are where to look to.Here are instructions to bring in the new framework with an MVC5 project:

http://scottdorman.github.io/2016/03/17/integrating-asp.net-core-dependency-injection-in-mvc-4/

Comment: According to this: https://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison, performance is not fast enough.

Comment: as of January 2022 the latest version of Unity is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

In this video a Microsoft MVP demos dependency injection in MVC5 with AutoFac. Very clear explanation on how to set it up:

[Dependency Injection MVC5 Demo](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Dependency-Injection?term=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection&lang-en=true)

Source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/miguelcastro67/DI-Webcast)

Answer (score 1):

From here https://scottdorman.blog/2016/03/17/integrating-asp-net-core-dependency-injection-in-mvc-4/

this line saved me.

```
    services.AddControllersAsServices(typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
      .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
      .Where(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t) 
       || t.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `Windsor`, by installing the nuget package `Castle Windsor MVC Bootstrapper`, then you can create a service that implements `IWindsorInstaller`, something like this:

```
public class ServiceRegister : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer container,
    Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        SomeTypeRequiredByConstructor context = new SomeTypeRequiredByConstructor ();

        container.Register(
            Component
                .For<IServiceToRegister>()
                .ImplementedBy<ServiceToRegister>().
             DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue<SomeTypeRequiredByConstructor>(context))//This is in case your service has parametrize constructoe
                .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

Then inside your controller something like this:

```
public class MyController 
{
    IServiceToRegister _serviceToRegister;

    public MyController (IServiceToRegister serviceToRegister)
    {
        _serviceToRegister = serviceToRegister;//Then you can use it inside your controller
    }
}
```

And by default the library will handle sending the right service to your controller by calling the `install()` of `ServiceRegister` at start up because it implements `IWindsorInstaller`

Answer (score -1):

Having started from this thread to figure out how to use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project, and reading and trying and failing, I finally came up with a solution that I wanted to shamelessly offer to the rest of you.

I pieced together a gist from David Fowler, the example code from Scott Dorman, and added in a bit of my own spice to create library that allows you to simulate ASP.NET Core's Startup in ASP.NET MVC "Classic".

For more information, please take a look at the GitHub repository for [Arex388.AspNet.Mvc.Startup](https://github.com/arex388/Arex388.AspNet.Mvc.Startup). If you're interested you can also read through my blog post about it, [here](https://arex388.com/blog/introducing-arex388-aspnet-mvc-startup-nuget-package-to-simulate-aspnet-cores-startupcs-in-classic-aspnet-mvc-applications) (if it doesn't load, refresh until it does, the server's been giving me troubles and I haven't had time to investigate...). Hope it helps someone!