# ASP.NET best practice for checking model's objects ownership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Right now I check the objects ownership of users like in code below (I commented important parts of code). And I do the same for every model and every controller method in my application, which completely violates the ***DRY*** principle. Maybe you have some ideas how I can avoid duplication?

Besides, I am not sure if it is safe and a user will not be able to access other people's data with some tricks. Is what I am doing is safe?

This is a very important topic regarding the security of personal data, and I'm sure there should be some kind of documentation. Unfortunately, I did not find any documentation, if I did not search well, I would be glad to see any links.

TasksController.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            // here I form a selection from objects belonging to the current user
            var Tasks = _context.Tasks.Where(t => t.UserId.Equals(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
            return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
        }


public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var task = await _context.Tasks.FindAsync(id);

            // here I check if the requested object belongs to the current user
            if (task == null | task.UserId != User.Identity.GetUserId())
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(task);
        }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,TaskTypeId,Status,UserId")] Task task)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // here i am assigning object's UserId to id of current user
            task.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            _context.Add(task);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(task);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to inject a work context object to the controller. Then get the user and other common information from that object which would reduce the repetitive codes. For example:

**Controller:**

```
private readonly IWorkContext _workContext;

public MyController(IWorkContext  workContext)
{
 this._workContext = workContext;
}
```

**Action:**

Instead of `User.Identity.GetUserId()` you do `_workContext.UserId`. This way if your identity logic changes then you do not have to change that in hundreds of places but only in the `IWorkContext`.

**Here is what would be in the `IworkContext` implementation:**

```
public partial class WorkContext : IWorkContext
{
    ...
    public virtual string UserId
        {
            get
            {
                return User.Identity.GetUserId()
            }
        }
}
```

You can define the `IWorkContext` interface accordingly and implement the necessary User based logic in there.

You can also have the `Task` property in the work context object instead of in different actions.

I have not included the *Dependency Injection* related code sample above. Which is not part of the question. You can read more about Dependency Injection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311099/how-to-create-dependency-injection-for-asp-net-mvc-5).

Comment: Glad that it helped. Hope you do not mind up voting the answer too :) Cheers!